# Show decimal numbers in Google Chart API

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, google-visualization

I'm working with a Google column chart here and I can't figure out how to display my values with decimals in my chart, the only way I can show my values is to include `.ToString(".")` which removes all decimals and just shows a whole number.

Is there a way to solve this, I'd like to have one decimal shown. e.g. `(6,2)`

```
<script>

    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);


    function drawVisualization() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Lift', 'Total', 'Squat', 'Benchpress', 'Deadlift'],
        ['Lift', @average.ToString("."), @saverage.ToString("."), @baverage.ToString("."), @daverage.ToString(".")],

    ]);
    var options = {
        title: 'Average reps per set',
        backgroundColor: { fill: 'transparent' },
        explorer: { axis: 'horizontal' },
        vAxes: {
            0: { logScale: false, viewWindow: { min: 0 } },
            1: { logScale: false, maxValue: 2 }
        },
        hAxis: { title: '' },
        seriesType: 'bars',
        curveType: 'function',
        series: {
            0: { targetAxisIndex: 0, color: '#20f400' },
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why is C# in the tags?

Comment: I'm using razor

Comment: [Google Wiki Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats) Maybe this will help

Comment: I believe the problem is that my decimal variable contains a comma and that the javascript chart wants a period to separate the whole number and decimals ? @LuudvanKeulen

Comment: Cant you use the replace method then? @average.replace(",",".")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google charts is expecting `.` instead of `,`
use `@average.replace(",",".")`